# how to improve action bar

Tags: android

I am making a sherlock action bar.It runs fine,but in its view,most of the part of the view is occupied by the application name and its action.I want to know that is there any way present to remove the application name and its icon from the action bar.This is the code :

```
public class NaseebactionbarActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.newlayout);
        ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.show();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu ) {
        com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item){
        // same as using a normal menu
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu1:
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,null);
           view.setMinimumWidth(200);
            view.setMinimumHeight(200);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams( new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            linearLayout.setOrientation(1);     
            linearLayout.addView(view);
            alertDialog.setView(linearLayout);
            alertDialog.show();
            break;
        case R.id.menu2:
            //makeToast("Saving...");
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void makeToast(String message) {

        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   
}
```

Comment: -1 repost http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602197/action-bar-view

Answer (score 1):

```
setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(); //Set whether an activity title/subtitle should be displayed. 
setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(); //Set whether to include the application home affordance in the action bar. Home is presented as either an activity icon or logo.`
```

Call these on your actionbar.

```
actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowTitleEnabled%28boolean%29)